# Receive the full Url incl. anchor via java script return function

Tags: javascript, return, google-tag-manager, return-value

i'm trying to get the full url via the following java script return function:
`function() { return window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname + window.location.search + window.location.hash; }`

The following function already worked for other domains. However, somehow I now don't receive any return for my single page application, when I fire this function as a custome java script variable in Google Tag Manager. Is there another way to receive the full URL?

Answer (score 0):

you don't need a js function here.
Go to variables in your GTM workspace, at the top you see "Built-in variables".
Click "Configure" and select "Page URL".
If you preview it the Page URL variable is populated with full URL.